# emquire.js and Chrome print dialog issu

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, backbone.js, media-queries, enquire.js

I have a piece of code this piece of code that gets executed as part of changing routes in a Backbone app:

```
mediaMatchUnRegister: function () {
            if (this.mediaMatchState.registered) {
                enquire.unregister(this.mediaMatchState.tabletAndUpQuery)
                        .unregister(this.mediaMatchState.mobileQuery);
                this.mediaMatchState.registered = false;
            }
        }
```

This all runs just fine, except under the following conditions:

1. App is running in Chrome
2. I have clicked the Print button on that page, which brought up the Chrome print preview dialog.

If I haven't brought up the Chrome print preview dialog then it runs just fine. FF and IE, which don't have this dialog, don't have any problems with this.

The issue is in `enquire.js`, specifically in the `clear()` method:

```
clear : function() {
                each(this.handlers, function(handler) {
                    handler.destroy();
                });
                this.mql.removeListener(this.listener);
                this.handlers.length = 0; //clear array
            },
```

If I haven't triggered the print preview dialog `this.mql` is a `MediaQueryList`. If I have triggered it then `this.mql` is now a `MediaQueryListEvent`. It then fails because this object does not seem to have the removeListener method.

Has anyone else encountered this? Is the Chrome print preview dialog a red herring?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue. I can't find a reasonable explanation so I just put a check before calling the `removeListener()`:

```
if(this.mql.removeListener)
```

it's far from ideal but atleast stops the code from breaking.